# Python の 'str' object does not support item assignment というエラーについて

Tags: python, python3

ある本を使って勉強しているのですが、本の通りにコードを書いてもエラーが出てしまいます。
このコードは、アルファベットを一文字ずつ入力していき、隠された単語にそのアルファベットがあればその部分が明らかになっていくという単語当てゲームのようなものです。

いつもエラーが出てしまうわけではなく、入力した単語が隠された単語（下記のコードではcat）に含まれないときには正常に作動しますが `c, a, t` のいずれかの文字を入力すると `'str' object does not support item assignment` というエラーが出てしまいます。

何が原因なのでしょうか。言葉足らずでしたら申し訳ございません。よろしくお願いいたします。
以下コードです。

```
def hangman(word):
    wrong = 0
    stages = ["",
              "________        ",
              "|               ",
              "|       |       ",
              "|       〇      ",
              "|      /|/　    ",
              "|      / /      ",
              "|               ",
              ]
    rletters = list(word)
    board = "_"*len(word)
    win = False
    print ("ハングマンへようこそ！")

    while wrong < len(stages) - 1:
        print ("\n")
        msg = "1文字を予想してね！"
        char = input(msg)
        if char in rletters:
            cind = rletters.index(char)
            print(cind)
            board[cind] = char
            rletters[cind] = "$"
        else:
            wrong += 1
        print(" ".join(board))
        e = wrong + 1
        print("\n".join(stages[0:e]))
        if "_" not in board:
            print("あなたの勝ち")
            print(" ".join(board))
            win = True
            break
    if not win:
        print("\n".join(stages[0:wrong + 1]))
        print("あなたの負け!正解は {}.".format(word))

hangman("cat")
```

Comment: 書籍のソースコードを使用しているなら、その出典も明記しましょう。またエラーメッセージについては略さずに全て記載してください。重要な情報が抜け落ちてしまいます。

Comment: [self_taught/python_ex239.py at master · calthoff/self_taught](https://github.com/calthoff/self_taught/blob/master/python_ex239.py#L16)

Comment: [コードを書き実行したのですが上手くいきません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/44863/)

Answer (score 1):

発生個所付近のソース記述や：

```
cind = rletters.index(char)
print(cind)
board[cind] = char
rletters[cind] = "$"
```

結果出力時のこれを見ると：

```
print(" ".join(board))
```

この記述で`board`が文字列になっているのが間違いで：

```
board = "_"*len(word)
```

その上の`rletters = list(word)`と同様に、リストにするのが一番修正量が少ないでしょう。

```
board = list("_"*len(word))
```

Comment: こっちだったのかも `['_'] *len(word)` ？

Comment: そういうのもありそうですね。コード入力時の見落としでしょうか。その場合出典が明らかになれば、何が原因かは直ぐにわかるでしょう。

Comment: あとエラー箇所も出てたはずで, それがあればもっと簡単に問題点気づけたかも(質問者さんが)

Answer (score 0):

```
board[cind] = char
```

を

```
board = board[:cind] + char + board[cind+1:]
```

としたらどうでしょうか？

前者のような代入方法はもしかしたら Python2 の時は可能だったのかもしれませんが、Python3 ではできないようです。